# What is the difference between `/etc/environment` and `/etc/profile`?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, posix

I understand that the former is loaded prior to the latter, but what is the difference in their purpose and otherwise? Are there any good reasons I should set some variables in one and not the other?

What little I understand is that `/etc/environment` seems to exist to set up environment for all processes run by the system, while `/etc/profile` is for setting up environment used and propagated from the login shell, correct?

And regarding the difference, which program traditionally reads `/etc/environment`? Is it related to POSIX, or just a convention?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`/etc/environment` is not part of POSIX, it belongs to PAM (Pluggable Authentication Module), and only programs compiled with PAM support are able to use it (primarily login systems, which subsequently start the shell or user environment). This means it isn't even read by your shell.

You can see the programs using `/etc/environment` with `grep -l pam_env /etc/pam.d/*`.

So `/etc/environment` is used for setting variables for programs which are usually not started from a shell.

Comment: according to `man enviroment.d`, systemd uses /etc/environment.d/, and for bc compatibility, a link to /etc/environment is created . With systemd, all processes get the variables.

https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/environment.d.5.html

Answer (score 34):

Extract from [The Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)

`/etc/environment` - This file is specifically meant for system-wide environment variable settings. It is not a script file, but rather consists of assignment expressions, one per line. Specifically, this file stores the system-wide locale and path settings.

`/etc/profile` - This file gets executed whenever a bash login shell is entered (e.g. when logging in from the console or over ssh), as well as by the DisplayManager when the desktop session loads.

I think all this is just a convention but not far from a standard (I don't know about RedHat like systems ).

Comment: It works on RedHat (as of 7.6). The '/etc/environment' is empty was my server and setting `VAR=value` took effect in a shell (after re-login).

Comment: I think one of the most important differences is that /etc/environment is not interpreted by bash - therefore expressions or external system calls just do not work.