# How to I persist prepended items to PATH in fish shell?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, path, fish

## My PATH Prefixes Don't Persist

I'm using Fish v3.2.0. According to the documentation, `set -U fish_user_paths` should *persistently* ensure that the directories stored in it should be looked up before other items in the *PATH*. However, it's inheriting *PATH* from somewhere else (a parent shell? a startup file of some kind?) and the *PATH* only changes if I manually set things in each shell instance.

### What Works (Temporarily)

```
> echo $PATH
/usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin/python

# This works, temporarily. It just doesn't persist.
> set -U fish_user_paths /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin
> set -SL fish_user_paths
$fish_user_paths: set in universal scope, unexported, with 1 elements
$fish_user_paths[1]: |/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin|

> which -a python
/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

### What Doesn't Work

```
# The changes to fish_user_paths don't get picked up
# by new invocations or subshells.
> exec fish -li
> which -a python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin/python

> set -SL fish_user_paths
$fish_user_paths: set in universal scope, unexported, with 1 elements
$fish_user_paths[1]: |/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin|

> set -SL PATH
$PATH: set in global scope, exported, a path variable with 5 elements
$PATH[1]: |/usr/bin|
$PATH[2]: |/bin|
$PATH[3]: |/usr/sbin|
$PATH[4]: |/sbin|
$PATH[5]: |/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin/python|

# Even trying to move the item doesn't seem to work.
> fish_add_path -Ppmg /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin/python
> echo $status
1
```

## Questions

These questions seem interrelated to me. I'm trying to discover:

1. Where is fish getting *PATH* from when I haven't set it explicitly?
2. Why can't I retain my *PATH* changes across shell instances?
3. Why am I getting an error when trying to use `fish_add_path` to modify *PATH* directly?

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, it may depend on your distribution, but likely `/etc/environment` if your login goes through PAM.  See [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/633526/1165986) and [this](https://superuser.com/a/664236/1210833).

For the second part, not sure yet.

For the third, I'm fairly sure it's because you are pointing it to a **file** rather than a **directory**, right?  The output of your `which -a python` says that `/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin/python` is the python executable, and yet that's the directory that you are trying to add.  Just a simple copy/paste error, I'm guessing.

I believe that ...

```
fish_add_path -Ppmg /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin
```

or

```
fish_add_path --move --path /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin
# Since the prepend and global should be default
```

... should work.

Once that's in place, does it help with the second part of your question at all?